# How can I add placeholder plugin for tinymce?

Tags: java, jsp, tinymce, placeholder

I am using tinymce editor in my web application. I need to add a placeholder to the editor. I have searched for 5 hours about it. But I couldn't find any solution or i couldn't understand how. Tinymce Editor is attached my project script library. I am sorry if there is a mistake in English.

I tried a solution which is available on [placeholder plugin](https://github.com/mohan/tinymce-placeholder). But I couldn't get it working. I have got some errors when add it to my tiny_mce/plugins folder.

Error: 
editor.on is not a function . ( plugin.js)

Could someone help me ?

It is tinymce.init code block :

```
tinyMCE.init({
// General options
language: "<%=sm.getVendorUser().getLanguage()%>",
mode : "specific_textareas",
editor_selector : "tinyMCEClass",
theme : "advanced",
relative_urls : false,
plugins : "fullpage,autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,visualblocks",

// Theme options
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols",//,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
//theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,visualblocks",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
theme_advanced_resizing : true,

// Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
content_css : "../styles/vedi.css",

// Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

// Style formats
style_formats : [
    {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
    {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
    {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
    {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
    {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
    {title : 'Table styles'},
    {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
],

// Replace values for the template plugin
template_replace_values : {
    username : "Some User",
    staffid : "991234"
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TinyMCE configuration would imply you are using TinyMCE 3.x and the placeholder plugin you are referencing (given its publication date and code I see in GitHub) was built for TinyMCE 4.

If you update to TinyMCE 4 it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but i got errors for theme property in this time. Advanced theme is not available on github

Comment: TinyMCE 4 does not have an `advanced` theme.   The default theme is called `modern`:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/themes/modern/  You will have to make a variety of changes to your TinyMCE configuration when moving from V3 to V4.  Please see: 
 https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/migration-guide-from-3.x/

Comment: Thank you ! . I converted it v3 to v4 .